# Looping with useState gets and unique key error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm doing a add multiple items to render in my browser, but when i click `addItem` the item renders but i get this error message:

'Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.'

[image]

```js
const newItem: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, setState]: any = useState([]);

  function addItem() {
    setState([
      ...state,
      <div>
        This is a Test
      </div>,
    ]);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <AllBets>
        {state.map((item: any) => (
          <BetsRange key={item.id} id={'div-parent'}>
            {item}
          </BetsRange>
        )
        )}
      </AllBets>
      <AddItem onClick={addItem}>
      </AddItem >
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look like your items have ids, so what is `item.id` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out fragment element that wraps your two elements, and it would not work at all, but I edited it anyways.

As far as the error goes, you get that error only if that `item.id` is the same for two or more elements.

If you are not sure what element is that, you can add one more guarantee that you will not get this error. Just add `index` as concatted string to id: `` key={`${item.id}${index}`} ``

```js
const newItem: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, setState]: any = useState([]);

  function addItem() {
    setState([
      ...state,
      <div>
        This is a Test
      </div>,
    ]);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <AllBets>
        {state.map((item: any, index) => (
          <BetsRange key={`${item.id}${index}`} id={'div-parent'}>
            {item}
          </BetsRange>
        )
        )}
      </AllBets>
      <AddItem onClick={addItem}>
      </AddItem >
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's it Mario, thanks for the explanation helped me a lot!

Comment: @Guilherme It is important to note, the key should not be `key={'${item.id}${index}'}`. Even though this is working for now it's not the cleanest solution. Since, your items do not have `id` field, the key should actually just be `key={index}`. Right now your keys looks like `undefined1` so forth

Comment: Well, leaving only `index` to be `key` is not the best solution actually. Because it leaves possibility of some other items arriving instead of existing and they get same `index` but dont get handled as expected. But anyways, `id` should be fixed and available for `key` use